# OEIS Sequence A002846 and properties of matrix inverses

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, oeis

Sequence A002846 in https://oeis.org/A002846 (OEIS) gives, for each positive integer $n$, the number $a(n)$ of ways of transforming a set of $n$ indistinguishable objects into $n$ singletons via a sequence of $n-1$ refinements, i.e. the number of ways of transforming a set of $n$ unlabelled objects into $n$ singletons via a sequence of $n-1$ binary partitions.

For a given $n$, each sequence of refinements can be represented by an $n\times{}n$ triangular matrix. The $(i,j)^{th}$ element of the matrix represents the number of sets after $i-1$ partitions that contain $j$ elements. The sum of the $i^{th}$ row is simply the number of sets after $i-1$ partitions, so is clearly $=i$. I am interested in linear combinations of these $a(n)$ matrices. For convenience, suppose that the coefficients total to 1. Then obviously if a matrix $M$ is formed by such a linear combination, the sum of the $i^{th}$ row is still $i$. However, a number of trials have convinced me that if $M$ is non-singular, the sum of the $i^{th}$ row of $M^{-1}$ is $\frac{i}{n}.$

To allow you to easily experiment, a list of matrices for n=4 to 9 can be obtained at github.com/helmutsimon/coalescent_tree_data . The file matrix_list_9 etc can be downloaded and then opened with pickle and gzip. The file then contains a python list of matrices represented as numpy arrays. At present, I have no idea how to go about proving this conjecture.

The following are the 4 matrices for n=5:

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 2.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 3.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 5.  0.  0.  0.  0.]

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  2.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 3.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 5.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 2.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 3.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 5.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  2.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 3.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 5.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]

The following are the 11 matrices for n=6:

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 2.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 3.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 4.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 6.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 2.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 2.  2.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 4.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 6.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 3.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 4.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 6.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 2.  2.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 4.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 6.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 2.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 3.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 4.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 6.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 2.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 2.  2.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 4.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 6.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 3.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 4.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 6.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 2.  2.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 4.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 6.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  3.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 2.  2.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 4.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 6.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  2.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 2.  2.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 4.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 6.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  2.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 3.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 4.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 6.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]

Comment: What if I am not a python expert?

Comment: You will also see some R code at the site which you can run to generate the trees yourself. It takes a while to run for n=8 or 9.

Comment: At the Wikipedia page it is explained that $a(n)$ is the number of chains of length $n-1$ in the poset of partitions with refinement order. Could you restate definition of your matrices in these terms? What I understand is that each of your matrices is determined by one such chain. Can you tell how to obtain it from that chain?

Comment: There seem to be some convention issues here which would be alleviated by including the relevant matrices for n=3 and n=4 in the question.  (I did try to download the suggested file, but for whatever reason was not able to gunzip it.)  If the 1st row is really supposed to represent the situation after 1-1=0 partitionings, then it would be a vector of length $n$, with a 1 in the final position, contrary to the assertion that the matrix is $n-1\times n-1$.  Also, it seems to me that the resulting matrices are not upper triangular since they are above the antidiagonal not the main diagonal.

Comment: @HughThomas I figured it out actually. Matrices are $n\times n$ lower triangular if by "$i$th row" one understands the $(n+1-i)$th row, i. e. refinements go from down to up. Example: $5\to41\to311\to2111\to11111$;
\begin{align*}&\text{the $1$st row corresponding to $11111$ is $50000$,}\\&\text{the $2$nd row corresponding to $2111$ is $31000$;}\\&\text{the $3$rd row corresponding to $311$ is $20100$;}\\&\text{the $4$th row corresponding to $41$ is $10010$;}\\&\text{the $5$th (last) row corresponding to $5$ is $00001$.}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thus e. g. the $n$th (last) row is always $000\cdots01$, the first row is always $n00\cdots00$, and the second row is always $(n-2)10\cdots00$.

Comment: @HughThomas I have corrected the errors (matrices should be nxn although top row and rightmost column are uninformative). Matrices are triangular above antidiagonal as you say. I have also added examples as suggested (the row entries are separated by dots for some reason). I hope this helps and thanks for your interest.

Comment: @Helmut: This question might be better suited for Math.SE. While it is a research problem for you, it might not necessarily be considered so by the standards of the mathematics community.

Comment: @AlexM. Do you mean it is easy? Or known?

Comment: Of the 15 matrices given, 13 have an all-zero column (and thus are singular).

Comment: @Gerry Myerson. True. But linear combinations of the matrices are generally non-singular (in fact with probability 1 if the coefficients are selected randomly).

Comment: Sorry, Helmut, I overlooked the "linear combinations" part of the question.

Comment: @Helmut Actually exactly one of them has all entries nonzero along the diagonal (and determinant is the product of these). So a positive linear combination is nonsingular if this one enters with nonzero coefficient in the combination (but also this is not necessary)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, this turned out to be embarrassingly simple. Let $M$ be such an $n\times{}n$ matrix and set $\mathbf{i}_n$ to be the column matrix with entries 1 to $n$ and $\mathbf{1}_n$ to be the column matrix with entries all equal to 1. By construction, each row of the matrix represents a partition of $n$. The first element of the row is the number of partitions of block size 1, the second element is the number of partitions of block size 2 and so on. So
$$M.\mathbf{i}_n=n\mathbf{1}_n$$
So if $M^{-1}$ exists:
$$M^{-1}.M.\mathbf{i}_n=M^{-1}.n\mathbf{1}_n$$
$$M^{-1}\mathbf{1}_n=\frac{\mathbf{i}_n}{n}$$